# import.meta undefined in components (Vite/Vue3)

Tags: environment-variables, vuejs3, vite

i am trying to access the import.meta.env Variable 'APP_SOCKET_URL' in my component but it says **Uncaught TypeError: import_meta.env is undefined**

In my main.js file import.meta.env works fine. In all other files it doesnt work and I dont know why. Maybe someone can help me there.

Here is the code of my data function:

```
 data(){


  const socket = new Socket(import.meta.env.APP_SOCKET_URL || `ws://${location.href}/ws`);
  return {
     socket
  };
}
```

In my .env file I added:

```
APP_SOCKET_URL="ws://localhost:8765"
```

And in my vite.config I changed the envPreix to "APP_"

Here is my Setup:

Vite Version 3.1.4 
Vue 3 Version 3.2.40
Programming in Typescript
Thanks and have a nice day!

EDIT:

I found the error. If I change the script lag from 'ts' to 'js' it works. So the problem is with typescript, but I dont know how to fix that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your answer should lie here in this [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#client-types)

Vite generates the types for you if configurated correctly in the tsconfig.json.